# Bootstrap Form Validation Not Returning Errors

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the code below saved in a file called index.html. This code has been copied from an example I found online here:

http://formvalidation.io/download/

For some reason, the the two inputs I have, as well as the checkbox, are not being validated. What I mean by this is that it should be giving an error if the email address that is typed in is invalid, but it is not. It should also be giving an error if the username is null and the checkbox is not checked. I've researched the formValidation() method that bootstrap has, but am unable to find a resolution. Any information on this issue is appreciated, thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="basicBootstrapForm" class="form-horizontal"
    data-fv-framework="bootstrap"
    data-fv-icon-valid="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"
    data-fv-icon-invalid="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"
    data-fv-icon-validating="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Email Address</label>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email"
                data-fv-notempty="true"
                data-fv-notempty-message="The email address is required"

                data-fv-emailaddress="true"
                data-fv-emailaddress-message="The input is not a valid email address" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">username</label>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username"
                data-fv-notempty="true"
                data-fv-notempty-message="The username is required" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="agree"
                        data-fv-notempty="true"
                        data-fv-notempty-message="You must agree with the terms and conditions" /> Agree with the terms and conditions
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="signup" value="Sign up">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#basicBootstrapForm').formValidation();
});
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include below script on your head section.

http://formvalidation.io/bundles/0a3b9034e109d88d72f83c9e6c9d13b7.js